# route query for play framework 1.2.5

Tags: playframework-1.x

I need to add a route for the following syntax:

```
http://www.testsite.com/select?term=query1
```

In my routes file, I tried using the following

```
GET    /select/{term}
```

However, the above does not catch the URL - instead it goes to another handler in the config (placed beneath the handler for select/{term}:

```
 GET     /{auth}
```

Any thoughts on fixing or troubleshooting this would be most welcome.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

?term=  means that term is a parameter - not part of the route you are trying to match

so you'd write

```
GET       /select              YourControllerClass.yourMethod
```

....

```
YourControllerClass extends Controller { 

public static void yourMethod(String term){ 
     Logger.debug("term=" + term);
 }
}
```

If your URL was `http://www.testsite.com/select/query1` then the route definition you provided above should work

Comment: it worked - thanks.  I'll check why the {auth} was working as a catchall for some reason

Comment: It was hitting the /{auth} route because /select matched it.  :)  If you look at the auth controller, you'd see it getting auth=select as a parameter.